# Get current user's phone number in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show current user's phone number on his profile page. I have used

```
<?php global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->user_login;
echo $current_user->user_email;
echo $current_user->user_level;
echo $current_user->user_first-name;
echo $current_user->user_last-name ;
echo current_user->display_name;
echo $current_user->ID;
?>
```

to get information of user. but when I using

```
echo $current_user->user_phone;
```

I don't get the phone number.

How can I get user's phone number?

Comment: Have you tried `get_userdata( $userid );` ? Also, what do you get in `echo $current_user` ? Paste it here.

Comment: How does your profile page look like? Here is a thread for phone numbers: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4028/how-to-add-custom-form-fields-to-the-user-profile-page

Comment: Yes I don't get from get_userdata( $userid );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the phone number, If anyone need then use

```
$user_phone = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'dbem_phone', true ); 
 echo $user_phone;
```

also get other fields data just get_user_meta( $user_id, 'field-name', true );

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php 
$current_user = get_currentuserinfo();
echo $current_user->user_login;
echo $current_user->user_email;
echo $current_user->user_level;
echo $current_user->user_first-name;
echo $current_user->user_last-name ;
echo $current_user->display_name;
echo $current_user->ID;
$phone = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'user_phone',true);
echo $phone;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get phone number of logged in user than you can use it.

```
$current_user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Return logged-in user id
echo $phone = get_user_meta($current_user_id,'phone_number',true);
```